# Are Feature Extractors Trained in the Tensorflow Object Detection API?

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, object-detection, object-detection-api

In the Tensorflow Object Detection API, a typical neural network will have 2 components: A feature extractor and then a neural network which uses the output of the feature extract to further classify an image.

If you were to custom train a faster resnet50 neural network in the object detection api, to detect an extra 2 objects, during the training process is the feature extractor also trained? I.E. does the weights of the feature extractor component change?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is trained by default. You can turn that off using the *freeze_variables* field in your train config. However, TF people discourage to do so, as they find it yields worse results and the same training time. See [this thread on github](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/2203) for more details.